# Custom Object how to get actual query data?

Tags: apex, trigger, query, data

I have two related custom objects. I'll name them: `Custom_Object1__c` 
and `Custom_Object2__c`. In the `Custom_Object2__c` I have a lookup field to `Custom_Object1__c`. In `Custom_Object1__c` I have a related list with `Custom_Object2__c`.

In `Custom_Object2__c` I also have a checkbox field. When changing the state of the checkbox I need in the `Custom_Object2__c` trigger to get all checked `Custom_Object2__c` records of `Custom_Object1__c`.

I've implemented a code in the trigger and I'm trying to get all checked `Custom_Object2__c` records via the following query:

```
SELECT checkbox__c, Custom_Object2_Status__c, Id FROM Custom_Object1__c where id =:Custom_Object1_ID__c
```

The issue I have is that the query returns old data which is before the update of the record. For instance I have four out of 4 checked `Custom_Object2__c` records but in the trigger the query returns 3 instead of 4 checked. How can I get the actual data?

Comment: Are you using `Before` or `After` Trigger?

Comment: I've tried both. No difference

Comment: So to clarify - you have a checkbox on CO2, and when you check/uncheck that checkbox on any CO2 record (say CO2R1), you want to fetch all such CO2 records which are associated with the Id of CO1 as on the current CO2R1 record, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code. I have tested the same in my developer org.
**Object Model:**
 [image]

And here is the code -
**Trigger :**

```
trigger ObjectB on ObjectB__c (after update) {
    new ObjectB_TriggerHandler().doAfterUpdateAction(Trigger.new,Trigger.oldmap);
}
```

**Trigger Handler :**

```
public with sharing class ObjectB_TriggerHandler {
    public void doAfterUpdateAction(List<ObjectB__c> newData, map<id,ObjectB__c> mapOldData){
        Map<Id, Boolean> validRecords = new Map<Id, Boolean>();
        for(ObjectB__c single : newData){
            if(single.IsChecked__c != mapOldData.get(single.id).IsChecked__c){
                validRecords.put(single.ObjectA__c, single.IsChecked__c);
            }
        }

        if(validRecords.size() > 0){
            process(validRecords);
        }
    }

    private void process(Map<Id, Boolean> validRecords){
        List<ObjectB__c> allObjectBRecords = [SELECT ID, IsChecked__c, ObjectA__c FROM ObjectB__c Where ObjectA__c in: validRecords.keySet()];
        for(ObjectB__c single : allObjectBRecords){
            single.IsChecked__c = validRecords.get(single.ObjectA__c);
        }

        Database.update(allObjectBRecords);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that you receive 3 records from query, because you are still in scope of update trigger and result (4th checkbox change) is not committed. Just get 3 values from database and the remaining 1 record is already in your trigger.new. Merge them in a new list or map and implement your logic on that list.